# jQuery.Deferred exception: Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь вставить значение из input. Когда прописываю строкой - все работает, когда тяну из переменной - **jQuery.Deferred exception: Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation**

```
 var city = document.getElementById('city').val;
$(function () {
                var params = {
                    'methodProperties': {
                        'CityName':city, //var city or string(string works)
                        'Language': 'UA'}
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/?' + $.param(params),
                    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                        xhrObj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        return Number;
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: '{body}'
```

вообще задача получать из инпута, по его изменении, слово и вставлять его в 'CityName', на данном этапе использую готовое значение инпута, но если подскажете решение для использования инпута по его изменению будет еще лучше (пытался с onchange и oninput но руки крюки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#city").keyup(function() {
  let city = $(this).val().trim();
  var params = {
    'methodProperties': {
      'CityName': city,
      'Language': 'UA'
    }
  };
  console.log(params.methodProperties.CityName)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="city">
```

Comment: супер, спасибо)